# How to get a value from a textarea and store it in a variable

Tags: javascript

I need to type something inside a textarea, then take the text that was written there and store it in a variable.

**Example:**

I type "Hello" in a textarea.

I want the variable to be: `x = "Hello"`

I've tried

```
document.getElementById("someId").value;
```

which doesn't work for me

```html
<textarea id="ide" rows="13" cols="60"></textarea>
```

Seems I didnt explain the question right, I wanted to store the value everytime you type but I found a way:

```
function val(e) {
     console.log(e.value);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ide" rows="13" cols="60" onkeyup="val(this);"></textarea>
```

and this is the answer in case anyone wondered, thanks for the replies!

```
function val(e) {
     var someText = e.value;
     console.log(someText )

     if (someText == "text") {  
          document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="new text"; 
     }
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_textarea_value.asp

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("ide").value;`

Comment: it works (just tested to be sure), maybe there's another problem in your code, can you show us a little more of it ? [fiddle of my test](https://jsfiddle.net/h0b41dz3/)

Comment: show your code so we can tell you why it isn't working. you're doing this right, which means you must be doing something else wrong. always show your code.

Comment: since you found the solution to your problem, you can create a self-answer and accept it so everyone can read it later. also it is generally considered bad practise to bind event in html

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell your program when you want the contents of textarea to be put into a variable.

For example, if you want it to happen every time you type something you need to add an 'input' event listener to the textarea:

```js
let text;
let textarea = document.getElementById('ide');
textarea.addEventListener('input', function getText() {
  text = textarea.value;
});
```

If you want to get the value when a button is clicked, then add click event to that button.

```js
let text;
let textarea = document.getElementById('ide');
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener('click', function getText() {
    text = textarea.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var valueInVar = '';
function textareaToVar(){
valueInVar = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
alert(valueInVar);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea" onfocusout="textareaToVar()"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi new contributor, you've made a good snippets which works, but doesn't tell why op code doesn't work, can you improve the answer in order to teach op why he got this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Address:<br>
<textarea id="ide" rows="13" cols="60">Hello</textarea>

<p>Click the button to change the contents of the text area.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ide").value;
  alert(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi , you've made a good snippets which works, but doesn't tell why op code doesn't work, can you improve the answer in order to teach op why he got this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your ID is different it is "someid" in your javascript and "ide" in your HTML. You need to change your code to:

```
<textarea id="ide" rows="13" cols="60"></textarea>

document.getElementById("ide").value;
```

You also need to make sure your DOM is loaded before trying to get the value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("delete").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
        //your code goes here
        alert('Alert message here');
    }
};
</script>
```